# Should I add one big vector overlay, or many smaller ones?

Tags: openlayers, kml

I'm creating a map application where I dynamically add kml based on DB query. It will be set of LineStrings - sometimes ten of them sometimes a thousand.
What is more efficient:

1. to create one big kml with all elements and stylings
2. to create one small kml per each line (advantage would be that I can tick/untick them with OL menu)
3. to add them via javascript:
   `addFeature('LINESTRING(20.0367 50.0727,20.0366 50.0727,20.0326 50.0757)');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient would be using WMS (via geoserver) and filter lines using CQL. Displaying thousand of features on one map might ruin the speed of application

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that creating potentially thousands of layers by putting 1 line X layer is not a good idea... your layers switcher control will be overwhelmed and at the end your browser will have to deal with the same quantity of vectors...

Point 1 and 3 may give you similar result but anyway, I suggest you to find a way to reduce the numbers of vectors/lines shown at the same time in your map because browser cannot easily deal with as much data... especially IE.

Using an OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX may help you extract from your db only the vectors needed in the current extent of your map...

Regards

Etienne